# @exportS3Method must be used with a function

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a function in arrow.R

```
#' @rdname arrow
#' @return An arrow array.
#' @exportS3Method arrow::as_arrow_array
#'
as_arrow_array.HArray <- function(x) {
  "whatever"
}
```

When I do:

```
rextendr::document() # basically equivalent to devtools::document()
devtools::load_all(".")
library(arrow)
```

Perfect!

But when doing:

```
library(arrow)
rextendr::document()
devtools::load_all(".")
```

I get the warning below and the method is not registered.

```
Warning message:
[arrow.R:37] @exportS3Method must be used with a function
```

Do you know why I am getting this warning?

Comment: I just discovered this bug and I am fixing it.